# Data compression and decompression

Tags: compression, lzw

i had research on different LZ family data compression. Among them the most popular algorithm is LZ77 an LZ78. But whats the different on LZcomp compression?

Answer (score 1):

LZCOMP is a LZ77 variant that includes several improvements also seen in LZSS or deflate as well as special optimizations for its field of application:

http://www.w3.org/Submission/MTX/#Theory

Comment: I studied the above w3c theory, but i get confuse whether LZW and LZCOMP is similar or different. is it just mention for MTX? or can be use for other compression methods? The algorithm mention in above link is only specified for MTX.

Comment: LZW is based on LZ78, not LZ77.
LZCOMP is specifically designed for that font format. While it should be possible to use it for other data as well its compression ratio might not be as good as other algorithms.